# React / JS - Fetch() - Assigning resulting array to a variable I can use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

Been banging my ahead against a wall on this one for a while. Doing the FCC course, essentially completed a project but trying to fetch a JSON with an array rather than just putting one in directly, myself, as I wanted to learn how to do it... Didn't think it would be this difficult!

**What do I want to do?**

I want to fetch a [json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json) and assign the array within it to state within my react component. I'll then use a random num gen to pick a random quote to display from the array.

**Where am I having trouble?**

I'm able to fetch the json and log the quotes to the console, however whenever I try to assign them to a variable, I end up with the promise object. I think it's a problem that I must've misunderstood/not quite wrapped my head around asynchronous functions yet

**What I need help with**

I've created a [new codepen](https://codepen.io/Jobeyobey/pen/OJEVvQa), separate to the task, where I have been testing how to get this to work without React, so I can then work it into my React project when I know what to do.

I'm able to log the first quote in the array to the console when I run the async function, however when I try to use that same async function to return that quote to myQuote, it returns a Pending Promise. Am I approaching this correctly at all, or am I completely going in the wrong direction?

If you don't want to visit the codepen link, code below:

```
const testFetch = fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((quote) => {
    return quote.quotes;
})

// The console.log below logs "The quote is [quote as a string]" to the console
const testVar = async () => {
    const quoteArr = await testFetch;
    console.log("The quote is ", quoteArr[0].quote);
    return quoteArr[0].quote;
};

let myQuote = testVar();

// This logs "Is my quote variable working? [Promise pending]" to the console
console.log("Is my quote variable working? + ", myQuote)
```

Comment: You didn't `await` you call to `testVar()`, I'm guessing that is why you're getting the Promise pending. Also, I'm confused as to why you would use the then() syntax together with the async/await syntax.

Comment: I did have a function that used `testVar` function that used `.then()` but I recall it giving the same result, this was another method I saw which just ended up the same as well.

To use `await` on the `testVar` call, I would just do `let myQuote = await testVar()` , right? This seems to just result in "this is only allowed within async functions"?

Comment: Yes, you cannot `await` something that isn't in an `async` function, but think of it this way: The only thing "stoping your code at an instruction, waiting for it to finish" is the keyword `await`. Meaning when passing on `let myQuote = testVar();`, the code is not stoped and the `console.log()` is displayed immediately, regardless of the response of your API call. That is exactly why the console right after the `await testFetch` works, because you `await`ed the result before logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern in react (although not the best one) is to call fetch in useEffect and set the state in .then.

The simplest example would be

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState<any>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((quote) => {
        setQuotes(quote.quotes);
      });
  }, [setQuotes]);

  return (
    <div>
      {quotes.length > 0 && quotes.map((quote: any) => <div>{quote.quote}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

A modern alternative in React is to use ReactQuery for fetching data, as it provides nice abstractions and caching out of the box.

Comment: Helped progress, thank you. FCC's course is a bit outdated, I had to do research into 'useEffect', 'useState', etc... I'd been doing the constructor, super, state etc...

The problem I'm having now: 

`console.log(quotes)`, gives the array of objects...

`console.log(quotes[0].quote)` gives undefined...

`console.log(quotes[0])` gives undefined...

`console.log(quotes["0"])` returns an object with `quote` key...

`console.log(quotes["0"].quote)`, throws an error. Wouldn't this essentially be the same method you used to map over the array?

https://codepen.io/Jobeyobey/pen/WNyvKzB

Answer (score 1):

In react, you need to load data after the render into the state. You can not just globally fetch and get data correctly. The below code will clarify.

```
const testFetch = fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((quote) => {
    return quote.quotes;
})

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
     testFetch.then(quoteArr => {
      console.log('The quote is ', quoteArr[0].quote);
    });
  },[])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is equivalent to the async/await syntax in that it is resolving the promise. It's a redundancy using both.

```
const testFetch = fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((quote) => {
    return quote.quotes;
})
```

You can try something like this

```
// you must also use react state to save your data
const [state, setState] = useState()

const testFetch = async () => {
  // with this syntax you need to wrap it in a try/catch to catch your errors
  try {
      // res here is equivalent to [response] above
      const res = await fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json')
      console.log(res)
      return res
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return
    }
  }

// and called upon component mount using useeffect
useEffect(() => {
  const testVar = testFetch()
  setState(testVar)
}, [])
```